# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError exception on some devices

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onclicklistener, samsung-mobile

I have an `ImageView` in my `Fragment`, on which am setting an `onClick Listener`.

```
public class TutorialFragment extends Fragment {

private TutorialAdapter tutorialAdapter;
private TutorialFragment tutorialFragment;
private SplashActivity splashActivity;
private RelativeLayout firstPageRelativeLayout,secondPageRelativeLayout,thirdPageRelativeLayout;
private ImageView backgroundImageView,facebookLoginButton,dekkohLogoImageView;
private ProgressDialogHandler progressDialogHandler;
private AlertDialogHandler alertDialogHandler;
private TextView firstPageTextView,secondPageTextView,thirdPageTextView,facebookPrivacyText,facebookDescriptionText;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater layoutInflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreateView(layoutInflater,container,savedInstanceState);

    tutorialFragment=this;
    splashActivity = (SplashActivity) getActivity();

    View v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.tutorial_fragment,container,false);
    firstPageRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.firstScreenRelativeLayout);
    secondPageRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.secondScreenRelativeLayout);
    thirdPageRelativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.thirdScreenRelativeLayout);
    backgroundImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.tutorialImageView);
    facebookLoginButton = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.facebook_login_button);
    dekkohLogoImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.dekkohLogoImage);

    firstPageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.firstPageTextView);
    secondPageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.secondPageTextView);
    thirdPageTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.thirdPageTextView);
    facebookPrivacyText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.facebookPrivacyText);
    facebookDescriptionText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.facebookDescriptionText);

    int currentIndex = (int) this.getArguments().getSerializable("tutorial");
    switch (currentIndex){
        case 0:
            firstPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            secondPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thirdPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(splashActivity).load(R.drawable.tutorial_1).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).fit().into(backgroundImageView);
            Picasso.with(splashActivity).load(R.drawable.dekkoh_logo_tutorial).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).fit().into(dekkohLogoImageView);
            break;
        case 1:
            firstPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            thirdPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Picasso.with(splashActivity).load(R.drawable.tutorial_2).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).fit().into(backgroundImageView);

            break;
        case 2:
            firstPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            secondPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            thirdPageRelativeLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Picasso.with(splashActivity).load(R.drawable.tutorial_3).priority(Picasso.Priority.HIGH).fit().into(backgroundImageView);
            Picasso.with(splashActivity).load(R.drawable.fb_login_btn).fit().into(facebookLoginButton);

            break;
    }
    final ArrayList<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    progressDialogHandler = ProgressDialogHandler.getInstance();
    alertDialogHandler = AlertDialogHandler.getInstance();


    facebookLoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // setting facebook permission
                permissions.add("email");
                // permissions.add("user_location");
                permissions.add("user_friends");
                progressDialogHandler.showCustomProgressDialog(splashActivity);

                final JSONObject jb = new JSONObject();

                Session.openActiveSession(splashActivity, true,
                        permissions, new Session.StatusCallback() {

                            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                            @Override
                            public void call(final Session session,
                                             SessionState state, Exception exception) {

                                if (session.isOpened()) {

                                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(
                                            session,
                                            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                                                @Override
                                                public void onCompleted(
                                                        GraphUser user,
                                                        Response response) {
                                                    if (user != null) {


                                                        String emaila = user
                                                                .asMap()
                                                                .get("email")
                                                                .toString();
                                                        String userId = user
                                                                .getId();
                                                        String name1 = user
                                                                .getName();

                                                        try {

                                                            jb.put("provider",
                                                                    "Facebook");
                                                            jb.put("user_id",
                                                                    userId.toString());
                                                            String token = session
                                                                    .getAccessToken()
                                                                    .toString();
                                                            jb.put("token",
                                                                    token);

                                                            Log.d("f b login ",
                                                                    jb.toString());

                                                            // clear seesion
                                                            // details and
                                                            // close
                                                            session.closeAndClearTokenInformation();
                                                            new LoginTheUser(
                                                                    token,
                                                                    user.getId())
                                                                    .execute();

                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                                            // e.getLocalizedMessage(),
                                                            // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                    } else {
                                                        progressDialogHandler
                                                                .dismissCustomProgressDialog(splashActivity);
                                                        alertDialogHandler
                                                                .showToast(
                                                                        splashActivity,
                                                                        "Facebook Login Failed!");
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                } else {
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });

    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(),"fonts/SortsMillGoudy-Regular.ttf");
    firstPageTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
    secondPageTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
    thirdPageTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
    facebookDescriptionText.setTypeface(typeface);
    facebookPrivacyText.setTypeface(typeface);
    return v;
}
```

This is running fine on Nexus, oneplus but I get the following error on some devices.

```
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.myapp.fragments.TutorialFragment$1
        at com.myapp.fragments.TutorialFragment.onCreateView(TutorialFragment.java:135)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:486)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:163)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1073)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:919)
        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1441)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:719)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:455)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:453)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1912)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1109)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1291)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The $1 signifies an Inner class, which is the `onclicklistener`. If I comment out the `onclicklistener` code, the Activity and the `Fragment` launch fine. Why is this? What is the issue?

Comment: where is your all code? post it...

Comment: Hi, I have added code of my entire fragment

Comment: Hey can you post you SplashActivity code? I'm facing the same problem and I want to know the cause ...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that your app reach the limitation of 65K methods, which is quite famous limitation of Android.

Ref: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html#dev-build

You can follow the solution in above link. Or in short:

If you have your Application class (you extends class Application), override attachBaseContext() in that class and call Multidex.install(this)

otherwise add this to your Manifest:

`android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

inside `<application>` tag.

Please reply here if it solves your problem. It solves mine actually.

Comment: Yeah. I just extended Application class and did Multidex.install in the onCreate() and solved it. Thanks

Comment: It helped me fix a similar issue in my app. Thanks.

Comment: If you were here, I would kiss you! Honest.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue running a Samsung Android 8.0 device, however no issue on Samsung Android 9. Enabling multidex and extending multidex application didn't help.

The only thing that fixed it was reducing the gradle tools version from 3.5.1 to 3.4.1 (com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1)